# Does Android market works on Beagle board(or any Third party board)? if yes How?

Tags: android, beagleboard

How to access android market through third party boards

Answer (score 2):

Android Market is only available to firms who license it for distribution on their devices. Hence, I am not aware of it being available for development boards. You may wish to consider using AndAppStore or SlideME's client for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried downloading directly from AndAppStore.com and it worked for me :)